# Sending successive HTTP requests from Android to HTTP server

Tags: java, android, apache, http, xmlhttprequest

I want to send two successive HTTP requests from my Android Application to the HTTP server, first request is for **Login** and second request is for retrieving the XML data on successful login. I have trying the following piece of code.

```
 public class XMLParser {
  public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {

    String xml = null;

    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost1 = new HttpPost(url);   //post for login
    HttpPost httpPost2 = new HttpPost(url);   //post for xml data

   // Building post parameters, key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePair1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "login"));
    nameValuePair1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "admin"));
    nameValuePair1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secret", "admin"));

    // Building post parameters, key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePair2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "sippeers"));

    try {
        httpPost1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair1));

        httpPost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair2));

        } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    try {

                //executing first http post
        HttpResponse httpResponse1 = httpClient.execute(httpPost1);

                //executing second http post
        HttpResponse httpResponse2 = httpClient.execute(httpPost2);
        HttpEntity httpEntity2 = httpResponse2.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity2);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return xml;

}
```

I want to execute first **httpPost1** and afterwards on successive login I want to retrieve the string **xml** from second HttpPost request. On executing the above code I am getting the error saying **Permission Denied**. I think I must maintain some kind of session while sending two HttpPost requests and should send second HttpPost request only on successful execution of first request.
Will be really thankful if someone can guide me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion, you save login data in cookie. """https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html""" this article show how to set cookie http request.